# How to Take Over Structures and Units?

Tags: achron

In the seventh mission of the first (human) campaign, the explanation of upgrades includes (after researching Aerospace) the hint "Taking control of unused structures to build-up forces". I must be missing something obvious. How does one capture 'unused' buildings and units?

This seems especially puzzling and worth knowing in the eighth mission, where there's a big bunch of Blackbird aircraft sitting in the base you get, but you can't command them (even by using the Nanite ability). Picking them up with the Carrier and letting them out results in them hovering in the air ever after.